# calling setState in flutter Bloc listener

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, bloc

I am calling setState in flutter BlocListener. is there any problem doing this?

```
....
return BlocListener<XBloc, XState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is XLoadedState) {
          setState(() {
            name = state.name;
          });
        }....
....
```

Comment: It's not a problem, but why would you want to do it? Why have a state outside of your bloc that is a copy of your state inside the bloc?

Comment: @nvoigt what if I have three separate ListViews on the same screen and data for these three ListViews will be available from a single source (database/service). I need to show an empty state while data is being loaded for these ListViews. In that case would it not be wise to call setState within BlocListener as the full screen need to be refreshed and loaded data will be shown?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem but it's kinda useless and anti pattern. And using `setState` you are forcing everything to rebuild even if it's not necessary.

You could just wrap the widget that uses `name` into a `BlocBuilder<XBloc,XState>`, for example like this:

```
BlocBuilder<XBloc,XState>(
  builder: (context, state){
    if (state is XLoadedState){
      return Text(state.name);
    }else{
      //return something for when state.name is null, I guess
    }
  }
)
```

You can check more about this [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#bloc-widgets)